# redirect all subdomains to www while setting environment variable

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, httpd.conf, configuration

I've got a domain (example.com) pointed to an apache2 webserver.

the root www folder looks like:

```
www/
  site/
  app/
  test/
```

The apache config should:

- send all requests to http://www.example.com/ to the 'site' folder.
- send all other subdomain requests to the 'app' folder, while setting the subdomains name as a environment variable.

I am sure that the DNS settings are correct, all urls get resolved to my webserver.

This is what I got in my apache configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory />
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
            AllowOverride All
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ServerName www.example.be
    ServerAlias www.example.be
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory />
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
            AllowOverride All
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ServerName example.be
    ServerAlias *.example.be
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/app/production/source
    SetEnv VAR_NAME %1
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The first VirtualHost, the www rewrite to the site folder works as it should be.

The second one does a correct rewrite, but I can't put the subdomain in the environment variable.

Can anyone help me with this last step? I'm not really an apache expert...

Thanx!

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what have the results been? Any log messages you can post?

Answer (score 0):

You say that a browser can't resolve a URL like http://test.example.com.  So is test.example.com a registered hostname in DNS?  If not, then your RewriteRule will never get a chance to fire because a client won't be able to find it.

If you're not sure if test.example.com is registered in DNS, try using any online DNS lookup tool, or from the command line run `host test.example.com` (Linux) or `nslookup test.example.com` (Windows).

Comment: Thanx Andrew, I've fixed the DNS, so now subdomains like test.domain.com get resolved to my server.

Comment: Good.  So does that fix your problem?  Please edit your post to clarify.

Comment: I've updated the question. I've made some progress but I got blocked at the environment variable.